# Problem with updating component state in the "Components" tab of React Developer Tools - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, developer-tools

I have a problem with Chrome extension - React Developer Tools, if I change component's state it's not changing in the dev tools window (as in the screenshot below) I am only able to see arrows with the title "Reset value".
Does somebody know how it could be fixed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp9Ms.png)

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it has a bug at this version, but if you select another component and then switch back and select your component again, you can see the updated state of it!

Comment: I am having this same problem. Has just started. Is there a fix for this yet?